# Numpy Nested Structured Arrays by reference

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, structured-data

I have the folowwing data structure:

```
N=100
TB =     {'names':('n', 'D'),'formats':(int, int)}
TA =     {'names':('id', 'B'),'formats':(int, dtype((TB, (N))))}
a = np.empty(1000, dtype=TA)
b = np.empty(N, dtype=TB)
```

where a is a structured array with two fields: 'id' and 'B'. In 'B' another structured array with fields 'n' and D is stored, e.g.

```
for i in range(0,1000):
   a['B'][i] = b
```

When the above assignment is executed, the data from b is copied to a. Is there a way to copy just the reference to b, so that when I change b, the change is reflected in `a['B'][i]`? What I want is to store pointers to b in a, because I dont need to create copies as the data in b is identical for every row of a.

I tired

```
TA = {'names':('id', 'B'),'formats':(int, object)}
```

and it works, but breaks the nested structure of the arrays. Is there a way the retain structured array functionality, e.g. `a['B']['D']`

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is no. Although the syntax for `numpy` arrays *looks* the same as standard python syntax, what's happening behind the scenes is very different. Complex `numpy` datatypes like `TA` use large blocks of contiguous memory to store each record; the memory has to be laid out regularly, or everything falls apart.

So when you create a 1000-item array with a nested datatype like `TA`, you're actually allocating 1000 blocks of memory, each of which is large enough to contain `N` distinct `TB` arrays. That's *exactly why* you can do things like `a['B']['D']` -- or, to point a point on it, things like this:

```
>>> (a['B'][1]['D'] == a['B']['D'][1]).all()
True
>>> a['B'][1]['D'][0] = 123456789
>>> (a['B'][1]['D'] == a['B']['D'][1]).all()
True
```

For normal Python objects, the above would fail, because object item access order matters. It's actually very weird that this is possible in `numpy`, and the only reason it's possible is that `numpy` uses uniformly structured contiguous memory.

As far as I know, `numpy` doesn't provide any way to do what you're asking (someone correct me if I'm wrong!), and the indirection required would probably involve significant changes to `numpy`'s API.

I'll add that I don't think it makes a lot of sense to do this anyway. If only one copy of the array is needed, why not just store it outside the array? You could even pass it around along with the numpy array, as part of a `tuple` or `namedtuple`.

Comment: thanks for you reply. I havnt thought about it in terms of access order, now I see you point. I've also thought of using namedtuples as you suggest, but still from an interface point of view a "pure" structured array solution would be desireble. After some trial & error I have broken down the problem to thw folowwing    asdsd

Comment: After some trial & error I have broken down the problem to the following: `A=np.ones(10); AA=np.empty(1, dtype=object); AA[0]=np.ones(10)`. If it's possible to convert AA to the type/dtype of A using AA.view() or AA.astype() then this would give the solution, but so far I havnt found a way

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just open a view. But it works the other way around as you described:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
>>> b = a[2:4].view()
>>> b[0] = 0
>>> b[1] = 0
>>> a
array([1, 2, 0, 0, 5, 6])
```

Comment: Assigning a view to a structured array also copies the data, soyour suggestion doesnt work. The workaround is to create an array with dtype=object, but is there a way to convert/open a view of such an arary to the original dtype?

Comment: maryam, a view does not copy the data. It is a reference to the same area in the memory, where the data is.

Comment: Not when you pass it to a structured array: `A=np.zeros(1,dtype='int,10int'); B=np.arange(10); A['f1']=B.view(); B*=0; print B; print A`

Comment: compare with: `AA=np.zeros(1,dtype='int,object');  B=np.arange(10); AA['f1'][0]=B; B*=0; print B; print AA` Now Im looking for a conversion/view of AA to resemble A